# Drag formulas across to last column

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that currently inserts formulas in 5 different places within a spreadsheet.
Due to the nature of the file these formulas will rarely be on the same rows each time it is run.
Which is causing an issue when trying to autofill the formulas across to the last column which will always be R for each formula that is within the file.
Thanks in advance for any help[image]

```
Dim WB As Workbook
Dim REC As Worksheet
Dim Rng As Range

Set WB = ThisWorkbook
Set REC = WB.Sheets("Reconciliation")
Set Rng = REC.Range("V:V")

'Insert Formulas
REC.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(2, 5).Formula = "=SUMIF($V:$V,""4"",F:F)"

REC.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).End(xlUp).End(xlUp).Offset(2, 5).Formula = 
"=SUMIF($V:$V,""3"",F:F)"

REC.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).End(xlUp).End(xlUp).End(xlUp).End(xlUp).Offset(2, 
5).Formula = "=SUMIF($V:$V,""2"",F:F)"

REC.Cells(Rows.Count, 
"A").End(xlUp).End(xlUp).End(xlUp).End(xlUp).End(xlUp).End(xlUp).End(xlUp).Offset(2, 
 5).Formula = "=SUMIF($V:$V,""1"",F:F)"

REC.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(5, 5).Formula = "=SUMIF($V:$V,"""",F:F)"
```

Comment: What's with all the `End(xlUp)`s?

Comment: @SJR The file splits into 4 separate sets of information and after a lot of trial and error this was the most effective way to get the formulas into the information as it always splits in a different way.

Comment: There will be a better way. Could you post a screenshot of a small sample of data?

Comment: @SJR Hopefully the image added will help

Comment: Not really, can't read it ! But try `REC.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(2, 5).resize(,18).Formula = "=SUMIF($V:$V,""4"",F:F)"` You might have to adjust the 18.